# PopUp Window. How to show full text content and two other questions

Tags: c++, qt, popup, qlabel

I created a popup window like this:

```
QFileInfo FileA = "AAA";  
QFileInfo FileB = "BBB";   

if (fileA.exists() == false & (fileB.exists() == false))
      {
          QFrame* PopupWin = new QFrame(this, Qt::Popup | Qt::Window  );
          PopupWin->setGeometry(450,450, 400, 200);
          PopupWin->setLineWidth ( 3 );
          PopupWin->setMidLineWidth ( 1 );
          PopupWin->setFrameStyle ( QFrame::Box | QFrame::Raised);
          QLabel *message = new QLabel(PopupWin);
          message->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
          message->setGeometry(100,50, 200, 100);
          message->setText("blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                             "bluuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu"
                             "bliiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
                             "bleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
                             "bloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
          PopupProzess->show();

      }
```

I have three questions:

- When the window pops up I can't see the whole text, just a part of
  the first line of the label. How can I show the whole text?
- The frame    is closed when clicking
  anywhere at the screen. How do disable this    "anywhere-click-close"
  and create a pushbutton or a kind of cross    that closes the
  frame/window?
- How do I fit the text right into the    label and the label right
  into the frame?

I searched in the Qt Doc and also googled, but did not find the solutions. greetings

Comment: See `QLabel::wordWrap` for showing the whole label: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop)

Comment: I exactly tried this in Qt Designer and it did not work, now I retried it and it works. Must have done something wrong the first time. thx for the tip.Anyway QLabel::setWordWrap(true) worked now for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a `QFrame`? What you want is a [`QDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDialog.html).

- Use the `QtDesigner` in order to design your dialog
- Implement a class inheriting from `QDialog` corresponding to the dialog you designed
- Use `exec` in order to show it modally.

This way your code will be cleaner and much easier to read.

```
QDialog* pMyDialog = new MyDialog(this); // you have to delete it later...
if (fileA.exists() == false && (fileB.exists() == false))
{
       pMyDialog->exec(); 
}
```

Also there is no reason to hardcode the geometry of a UI element. This is what `QtDesigner` is for.

Concerning the label, as spbots already answered you have to set the `wordWrap` property.